# I need to restore from $Recycle.bin more than 40000 items

Tags: powershell

I need to restore from Recycle Bin more than 40000 items, by GUI its uses a lot of memory and the system almost hangs, even if I make 100 items at a time. Thus, I wrote the following script in PowerShell, but I have the following error:

```
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Move Directory" on target "Item: E:\$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-5-21-45987200-1508583899-68119131-500\$R2FXY9E Destination: E:\OneDrive - MHG - Brasil\Admin_Fin\Silvia\Silvia\Clientes\Miller Heiman Group\Embraer\Fase I\ARIBA\Embraer - Evento - Resumo_arquivos".
Move-Item : Could not find a part of the path.
At E:\Scripts\ListaRecycled.ps1:7 char:6
+      Move-Item $item.Path $CaminhoCompleto -Force -Verbose
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (E:\$RECYCLE.BIN...31-500\$R2FXY9E:DirectoryInfo) [Move-Item], 
DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveDirectoryItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

In my code, I am doing the following:

```
$Shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$Global:Recycler = $Shell.NameSpace(0xa)
$Excluidos = $Recycler.Items()
foreach ($item in $Excluidos)
{
  $CaminhoCompleto = Join-Path $Recycler.GetDetailsOf($item,1) $Recycler.GetDetailsOf($item,0)
  Move-Item $item.Path $CaminhoCompleto -Force -Verbose
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think you have an object in your bin that has a blank or otherwise invalid name. I tried your code above and it turned out I had a folder with no name (no idea where it even came from) but it broke because of the way the join-path function runs. It found the old path and tried to concatenate a blank name to it and then tried to move it over the base folder. Not sure if that is your problem here as well but it's worth checking the contents of your bin to ensure you don't have any blanks.

Comment: You can use the item's properties to determine the destination. `$item.getfolder.title`

Answer (score 2):

You are using positional parameters, not named. `Move-Item` takes argument at position 0 as the `Path` parameter, which is subject to shell globbing.

You should generally be using named parameters anyway, and in this case you really want to use `-LiteralPath` and not `-Path`.

```
Move-Item -LiteralPath $item.Path -DestinationPath $CaminhoCompleto -Force -Verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered. The `Move-Item` cmdlet does not create a folder path, thus I added the following on my script:

```
if(!(Test-Path $Recycler.GetDetailsOf($item,1)))
 {
   New-Item -Path $Recycler.GetDetailsOf($item,1) -ItemType Directory -Force -Verbose -OutVariable +Dir

 }
```

I discovered too that was missing DACL of items. Then I added the following:

```
$permissoes = Get-Acl $item.Path -Verbose
Move-Item -LiteralPath $item.Path -Destination $CaminhoCompleto -Verbose -ErrorVariable +Err     
Set-Acl -Path $CaminhoCompleto -AclObject $permissoes -Verbose
```